Why is SELECT IN (strings...) faster than SELECT IN (numbers...)?
I have the following oracle table (minimal for this question)
create table my_table
(
    selecting_by    NUMBER(10),
    wanted_value VARCHAR(100),
)

And the following SELECTs:
-- Select as strings
SELECT wanted_value as wv FROM my_table WHERE selecting_by IN ('1', '2', '3');

-- Select as numbers
SELECT wanted_value as wv FROM my_table WHERE selecting_by IN (1, 2, 3);

It turns out, for every Oracle DB (job's production db and locally a smaller PoC on my laptop) the first query is faster than the second one (on my PC it was 2 times faster, and in production is 30 times faster, which is not negligible).
These are some statistics that I extracted from my PoC:

LongSummaryStatistics{count=800, sum=78002, min=58, average=97.502500, max=690}
LongSummaryStatistics{count=800, sum=136886, min=59, average=171.107500, max=3654}

The code runs in java (both production and personal) and from what I seen on JProfiler, the issue is from query execution (not query creation/building).

What data is in the tables? Is this just for the first elements to return, or for the full resultset? How to the explain plans look like?

If you are thinking about performance you should not use the IN operator.

You said in Staging that EXPLAIN PLAN produces identical output in both cases. It would be worth adding this information to the question. Also, it would be worth adding the Java code you are using, to show: 1. how are you measuring the times? 2. how are you supplying the parameters - literally or though a parameterised query?

@k314159 Why do you think they have to be compared to a text column? According to the question, the column is of type number.

@JonasMetzler ah, yes, you're right. I thought it was comparing wanted_value. I've deleted my comment to avoid future confusion.

Note that Oracle11 is extremely obsolete and no longer supported since about 4 years. You should urgently upgrade.

Any performance question has to start with examining your wait profile, either via SQL Monitor report, or querying ASH data, or OEM or some other tool that leverages the same data. You have to look at the plan and see where time was spent in it. Then you can solve your problem methodically. But off hand, I'd suggest looking at the datatype of your selecting_by column. If it's a varchar2/char column and its indexed, that'd be why it's faster than querying it with numbers. If you criss-cross your predicate datatype with the column datatype, an implicit conversion will throw out index use.

Oracle 11 may be obsolete from a support perspective, but it still works well and is not to blame for poor performance. Many orgs have lots of legacy apps on older versions. Hardware matters more than DB version.

Here are some minimal hints what you should provide for a performance related question.

I will update the question tomorrow and consult with other colleagues to avoid some leaks.
Update: I found the issue. It looks like PreparedStatement is faster than a string query; this is true only for OracleDB; on MySQL, there's no performance change.

@Paul W, the column selecting_by is indexed, and it is number(10)r, and it is faster to search it in ('1', '2', '3') than (1, 2, 3)`. I think it is something related to parsing. As I mentioned above, the PreparedStatement fixed the issue.
As a bit of context, the queries were created with stringBuilders on the application side. However, they're safe from SQL injection because they always concatenated numbers. But right now, it looks like more security is better in terms of performance :D

@Tuddi, in that case, I'll bet that selecting_by is not a selective column, and that using the index is the wrong thing to do; a full table scan may be faster. Without knowing your data we're all guessing here. Try dropping the index and then use numbers in your query. I'll wager you'll see it perform similar to the string version, because then it will do a full scan no matter what. As a rule we do not like to see datatype mismatches between queries and data columns; it causes numerous issues in other situations. But it may be that in this particular situation, it's avoiding a bad index.
